# How do I prove that $p = x^2 +2y^2 $ iff p $\equiv$ 1 $\mod{8}$ or p $\equiv$ 3 $\mod{8}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The title pretty much says it. If $p$ is an odd prime, how do I prove the following?: $p = x^2 +2y^2 $ iff p $\equiv$ 1 $\mod{8}$ or p $\equiv$ 3 $\mod{8}$

Comment: This type of question has been answered a number of times. It boils down to showing that $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$ if and only if $p\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).